# PowerShell Hyper-V Add network elements to VM object

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

We're gathering system information for a fairly large installation including Hyper-V virtual machines.  As part of that effort, we're inventorying the attributes of the VMs, and we'd like to associate the IP address (or first IP address) with the VM.

To that end, we have the following script, which details the items we want to collect.  Then, for each element of the group, we would like to add the (first) network adapter information.  However, the Add-Member that you see in the middle part of this script seems to have no effect; the script outputs the same whether we include that ForEach or omit it, and I don't understand why.  Is it not valid to use Add-Member for this sort of object (there is no error, though...)?  Can you point out where this script might be going wrong?

```
$VMs = Get-VM `
     | Select @{Name='Hostname';Expression={$(hostname)}} `
             , VMName, VMId, Id `
             , AutomaticStartAction, Uptime, OperationalStatus `
             , PrimaryOperationalStatus, Status, ReplicationHealth, ReplicationState `
             , CheckpointType, VirtualMachineType, VirtualMachineSubType `
             , State, HardDrives, MemoryMaximum, MemoryMinimum,MemoryStartup `
             , ProcessorCount, Path,SizeOfSystemFiles, ReplicationMode `
             , ResourceMeteringEnabled, Version, FibreChannelHostBusAdapters `
             , DynamicMemoryEnabled, CreationTime, IsDeleted 
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
         $Adapters=($VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter)
         $firstAdapter = "Yes"
         ForEach ($Adapter in $Adapters) { 
             if ($firstAdapter -eq "Yes") {  <# Prevent fail if more than one adapter is present. #>
                 $ip4 = $Adapter.IPAddresses[0]
                 $ip6 = $Adapter.IPAddresses[1]
                 $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Adapter -value $Adapter.Name
                 $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -value $Adapter.IPAddresses[0]
                 $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP6 -value $Adapter.IPAddresses[1]
                 $firstAdapter = "No"
                 }
             }
         }
$VMs | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
     | Set-Content -Path \path\to\myfile.csv
```

By the way, if my newbie-ness shows from the use of ForEach() with a test to ignore all but the first... I'd love to see suggestions for a better way.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just realized I did not Select the network information.  A restructure to the script, moving the select to the end, solved the problem.  I'll vote to close my silly question.

Answer (score 0):

This required a restructure of the script.  Since Network Adapter information was not passed into Get-VMNetworkAdapter, it produced no output.

This script works:

```
$VMs = Get-VM 
ForEach ($VM in $VMs) {
         $Adapters = $VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter
         $firstAdapter = "Yes"
         ForEach ($Adapter in $Adapters) { 
             if ($firstAdapter -eq "Yes") {  <# Prevent fail if more than one adapter has IP4. #>
                 if (-not $Adapter.IPAddresses -eq $null) {
                    }
                 else {
                     $ip4 = $Adapter.IPAddresses[0]
                     $ip6 = $Adapter.IPAddresses[1]
                     if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ip4) ) {
                         $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NetAdapter -value $Adapter.Name
                         $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -value $ip4
                         $VM | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IP6 -value $ip6
                         $firstAdapter = "No"
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
$VMS | Select @{Name='Hostname';Expression={$(hostname)}} `
             , VMName, VMId, Id `
             , NetAdapter, IPAddress, IP6 `
             , AutomaticStartAction, Uptime, OperationalStatus `
             , PrimaryOperationalStatus, Status, ReplicationHealth, ReplicationState `
             , CheckpointType, VirtualMachineType, VirtualMachineSubType `
             , State, HardDrives, MemoryMaximum, MemoryMinimum,MemoryStartup `
             , ProcessorCount, Path,SizeOfSystemFiles, ReplicationMode `
             , ResourceMeteringEnabled, Version, FibreChannelHostBusAdapters `
             , DynamicMemoryEnabled, CreationTime, IsDeleted `
     | Select * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName `
     | Select * -ExcludeProperty ComputerName `
     | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
     | Set-Content -Path \\gotprmry07\PerfLogs\SystemInfo\$(hostname)-VM-details.csv
```